# Issue updating domain name servers from BlueHost to AWS

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, nameserver

I am trying to migrate my site hosting from bluehost to AWS cloud based service.

I have the site up and running on AWS with an elastic IP configured, it loads fine when I specify the IP address in the browser.

I have gone into Route 53 on the AWS console and created a "hosted zone" for the domain. I then created a new record set of type "A" using the IP address as the value.

I have a domain name registered with bluehost. Ive logged into the bluehost account and updated the domain name servers to point to those specified in Route 53 in the AWS console.

When I hit the IP address directly the site loads, however it doesn't load when using the domain name (I get a google chrome oops error page saying page is not found)

I've tried using this site: http://dns.squish.net/ to debug but it seems to be giving me the correct results.

```
fizaclegems.com 300 IN  A   107.20.209.78
```

Where 107.20.209.78 matches the elastic IP configured in the AWS console. This is the result it gives for all 4 name servers.

Am I missing a step here? Does anyone know what else I should be doing or looking for?

Comment: People might be able to offer more assistance if you provided the actual host name and IP address.

Comment: Ok, updated the question

Comment: And it worked :-)

Answer (score 2):

fizaclegems.com appears to 301 redirect to www.fizaclegems.com, which has no A or CNAME record.

```
[] csternal@~: dig fizaclegems.com

; <<>> DiG 9.6-ESV-R4-P3 <<>> fizaclegems.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 20507
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;fizaclegems.com.       IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
fizaclegems.com.    300 IN  A   107.20.209.78

;; Query time: 142 msec
;; SERVER: 10.0.1.1#53(10.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Dec 29 14:39:45 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 49
```

Versus:

```
[] csternal@~: dig www.fizaclegems.com

; <<>> DiG 9.6-ESV-R4-P3 <<>> www.fizaclegems.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 46305
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.fizaclegems.com.       IN  A

;; Query time: 13 msec
;; SERVER: 10.0.1.1#53(10.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Dec 29 14:40:16 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 37
```

Comment: Great shout, Ive added an extra A record for www.fizaclegems.com and it seems to be loading correctly now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If this fixed your problem, please accept the answer by pressing the checkmark by it.

Comment: Annoyingly I've posted it under some strange account that I cant log back into...